# How to get an rgl plot output under Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgl

When plotting something with the `rgl` package for `R` on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine, how can I get any plot output?

When I run a plot command, I am not getting any plot window or visual output. E.g., the README of rgl suggests the following to run a demo:

```
library("rgl")
demo("rgl")
```

but it shows no plot windows when I browse through the demos (by hitting return several times). All I get is text in the R console.

##### What I have tried:

I noticed the following during the rgl package installation:

```
install.packages("rgl")
```

This completes without error, but I get the following message during the configure phase of the build process:

```
checking for X... no
configure: WARNING: X11 not found, continuing without OpenGL support.
```

and if I load rgl afterwards, using `library(rgl)`, you get a notice:

```
 library(rgl)
This build of rgl does not include OpenGL functions.  Use
 rglwidget() to display results, e.g. via options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE).
```

If I follow the advice given there, i.e., first run `options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE); demo(rgl);`, then it opens one tab in my browser (firefox) per demo, and all tabs show `File not found` errors for temporary files like `/tmp/RtmpWqj4zX/viewhtml53511cd8b2f5/index.html.`.

I am running a graphical user interface, so I found it strange that X11 was not being found, maybe this is because my system is using Wayland: `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` outputs `WaylandEnable=true`. However, this is pure speculation.

To repeat, my question is, how can I get rgl plot output under Ubuntu 22.04? I would prefer to have an X11 window open, but the browser-based rendering would be better than nothing.

##### System info:

- Ubuntu version (the VERSION of `cat /etc/os-release`): 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
- R version (from `R --version` in shell): 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
- rgl version (from `packageVersion("rgl")` in R): 0.110.2
- Note: This is a machine under control of our IT department, I have no root access.

Comment: I can reproduce this using firefox. Using [brave](https://brave.com/download/) as standard browser it looks better, have you tried that? I think this has to do with different right management of both browsers, not exactly sure.

Comment: I also noticed that the files in /tmp actually exist. Sadly firefox is the only browser installed and I have no root access, so I cannot test easily. I will talk to IT about getting an alternative browser installed.

Comment: Can you try to open an `*.html` file which is located on the server, either by clicking and open with firefox or by typing  e.g. `file:///.../.../foo.html` into address line? I noticed that it won't work with firefox but with brave. I think there's the rub, can you reproduce that?

Comment: Trying to open the file manually in firefox leads to the same error, I had already tried that. I have installed chromium (from the Ubuntu snap-store) for my user, and it shows identical behavior, the error message here is 'Your file couldn’t be accessed'. In the terminal, it prints: `ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization` while that happens. Sounds like a WebGL problem, but I can run all demos at webglsamples.org fine in both browsers, so that is not the case.

Comment: Just tried that, I installed you suggested chromium snap, and it didn't work, whereas it does work with brave. Maybe give brave a shot its also available as snap `sudo snap install brave `.

Comment: I installed brave, but it also shows the same behavior: file not found error, even though the file exists. `brave --version` output: `Brave Browser 108.1.46.144`.

Comment: Weird, also using that version, and same version Ubuntu.

Comment: You may need to get an admin to do this, but you should run `aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev` before trying to build `rgl`.

Comment: The other possibility is to use one of the pre-bulit rgl binaries available for Ubuntu.  I think running `apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-rgl` will give you that, but I'm not an Ubuntu user, so I may have missed some prerequisite.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks, having IT install ibgl1-mesa-dev and libglu1-mesa-dev, then reinstalling rgl did the trick! I was also missing freetype, but that's another story. Would you care to add this as an answer?

Comment: `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev` did the trick for me too ! (wayland under 22.04) thanks!

Comment: Nice, why not making an answer out of it?